# Каково происхождение слов «гарантии» и «карантин»?

Tags: этимология

Слова *гарантия* и *карантин* звучат очень похоже.
Между ними прослеживаются и смысловые соответствия.  К примеру, оба термина могут истолковываться как  ряд оговоренных условий, которые должны быть обеспечены и неукоснительно соблюдаться.
Слово *гарантировать* имеет значения ограждать и защищать. На то же направлены *карантинные* мероприятия: ограничение транспортного сообщения, блок посты, самоизоляция, дистанцирование, а кроме того - защитные маски, перчатки, средства обеззараживания…

Может быть, у этих слов общая основа?  Только она никак не ощущается, даже если похожие слова расположить рядом: «строгое исполнение *карантинного* устава даст *гарантию* нераспространения инфекции».

Answer (score 2):

"Карантин" от итальянского слова "quaranta" (сорок). Столько дней должны были простоять торговые корабли вдали от берега, прежде, чемм их впускали в порт и разрешали экипажу сходить на землю (то ли в Генуе, то ли в Венеции).

"Гарантия" родом из французского, берет начало от старофранцузского слова, означающего "приказчик, пристав, лицо, обеспечивающее выполнение закона". Английские [warranty](https://www.babla.ru/%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B9%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D1%80%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9/warranty) и [warrant](https://www.babla.ru/%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B9%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D1%80%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9/warrant) оттуда же, так же как и немецкое [wahren](https://www.babla.ru/%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%86%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D1%80%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9/wahren).

Этимологически ничего общего между "гарантия" и "карантин" нет.